# Confusion over current terms: frontend, backend, API

Tags: frontend, backend

I've been thinking a lot lately about the terms used to describe the different types of web developers these days. I feel like the term "front-end" has become synonymous with client-side and "back-end" with server-side. For instance, if you modify a site's Javascript or CSS, that's front-end, but if you modify the controllers and views of a Rails project, that's back-end. This seems confusing, especially with the advent of front-end frameworks like Backbone.js. At that point, both front- and back-end developers are injecting logic to the web app.

I've done work on both sides, but I don't consider myself a full-stack developer. For instance, adding logic to a Rails app to loop over 30 items and display them properly still seems like front-end work to me. In my job experience, anything deeper (like CRUD work, statistics analysis) involves calling an API in another app that the company I work for has created. So then what are the developers who are creating that logic called? That, to me, seems more descriptive of a back-end. Or is there another term I'm missing here, like platform developer?

Thoughts?

Comment: to me, 'front end' = ui, design. 'backend' = the logic that powers it, wherever it resides.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I found [this](http://blog.salsitasoft.com/the-shifting-definition-of-front-end-developer/) article had a nice, logical discussion of the differences and how they came to be.

Answer (score 0):

web application elements
UI design---- Photoshop design for User Interface
UI developement----converting photoshop design to html,css
Front end development--- converting html/css and add functionality with javascript, or javascript frameworks(jquery,prototype etc.,) and ajax .
creating aspx file in visual studio and front end in eclipse also comes under
Front end development.
Programming like c#, java, php etc., comes under backend , we can include database in this backend. But as per the scenario the backend and frontend terms changes acccordingly.